# How to store a score after starting new game

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, store

I am making a project for a guessing number game. So far, everything goes good but I am still struggling with a method to store the score after starting new game. For example, when the user wins or loses, the score will record the results. The user can click the button to see the score during the game. The program will ask if the user wants to continue or not. If so, the program will restart but it won't reset the score. The score will remain until the user closes the program. That is what I want but I am still stuck on making it work. If anyone could help out with it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main: Form
    int attempt;
    int randomNumber;
    int count;
    private static int wins;
    private static int loses;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        attempt = 0;
        wins = 0;
        loses = 0;
        count = 10;
        randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
        StartNewGameButton.Visible = false;

    }

    private void Guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        int guess = 0;
        guess = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        attempt++;
        label4.Text = "Guess Attempt: " + attempt;

            if (guess == randomNumber)
            {
                wins++;
                label4.Text = "Your guess is correct! Game Won";
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = false;
                GuessButton.Visible = false;
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to play again?", "Start a new game", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Application.Restart();
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                } 
            }
            else 
                if (guess < randomNumber)
                {
                    label2.Text = "Too low!";

                }
                else if (guess > randomNumber)
                {
                    label2.Text = "Too high!";

                }

             if (attempt == count)
                {
                    loses++;
                    label4.Text = "Sorry, You missed it! Game Lost";
                    label2.Text = "The answer is " + randomNumber;
                    label3.Visible = false;
                    GuessButton.Visible = false;
                    StartNewGameButton.Visible = true;
                }
        }


    private int generateRandomNumber()
    {
        Random number = new Random();
        int randomNumber = number.Next(1, 100);

        return randomNumber;
    }

    private void StartNewGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }

    private void CheckScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Win: " + wins + "\nLose: " + loses);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. Wont this do what you want?

```
private void CheckScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if ( MessageBox.Show("Win: " + wins + "\nLose: " + loses + "\n\nDo you want to Continue?", "Continue?",
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
   {
      Form.Close();
   }
   else
   { 
      // Reset as necessary
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure i got it right but i think the problem you are facing the when you call the application.restart method the int wins becomes 0 again 
there is more than one to solve this  :
First save the int wins and int loses in a file using file stream or using a very small sql compact database and this way u can save the score easliy and view it anytime even if the after restarting the user's pc

a very very very much easier way , you don't have to restart the whole app to start a new game ..you can use the go to keyword which will re-execute your code from any line you want

and btw did u really have to create a whole method to generate a random 
you could just say :

```
 Random number = new Random();
    int randomNumber = number.Next(1, 100);
```

in the beginning of the guess click event handler

Comment: any developer should have a background about databases and learn how to create one , you are creating this app to gain experience and learn more so this is a good chance to store knowing more about databases in my opinion ,,, i can't explain every thing about databases in just one comment but think of it as collection of data that is organized and can be easliy edited or viewed , so u can create a database and insert the scores in it ...try this tool it will make your like much easier 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1